# Get the Current Temperature in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to create a small weather app.

What is the best practice to figure out what degree setting the user have? (Celcius or Fahrenheit) Is it possible to read that from the built in weather app?

Comment: I'm confused. Weather is not a user-defined setting, It's something that you would read from a web server, like `weather.com`..

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I think you misunderstood the question from the OP. I think it was a lot simpler: the OP wanted to know what's the preferred way to display the temperature in the current locale of the user, assuming that his program already knows what temperature to display.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hmm, it's possible that I misread the OP, but it wasn't worded very well either way.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I agree, the wording was indeed somewhat ambiguous. I guess we should wait for the OP to come back and edit the question with the clarifications that you requested in your initial comment.

Answer (score 15):

To answer the original question about the display settings, I'd try this:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; 
BOOL usesMetric = [[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];
```

If `usesMetric` is `YES`, I would use Celsius; otherwise, I'd use Fahrenheit.

Comment: Perfect I'll use that in my next version of the iPhone/iPad app: "The Sun - Rise and Fall"

Comment: @user1310911 if this is the answer you were looking for, please consider reverting the edit of your question, otherwise my answer seems to be completely off the mark (I think Richard misunderstood your question). Consider also accepting one answer. [Here is a link on how to do it, and why bother.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 7):

You would need to find a web API for this, here are a few:

1. [World Weather Online](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx) (free)
2. [The Weather Channel API](http://portal.theweatherchannel.com/?) (paid subscription)
3. [Weather Underground API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api) (free)
4. [WeatherBug API](http://weather.weatherbug.com/desktop-weather/api.html)
5. [yr.no API](http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to read the weather from anywhere on the phone, including other apps...the iPhone Weather app uses the Yahoo weather API. You can use that or the Google one: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/02/08/googles-secret-weather-api/

There is no way to get around it without a server call :)

(I am assuming you are interested in the weather and not just the temperature).

Comment: Note to future readers: Google's "secret" weather API is no longer available.